# Java Generics and generic types

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class ExtA which contains a filter function to filter an ArrayList:

```
public ExtA<T> filt(...)
{

 //code


}
```

when I compile it is giving me error: cannot find symbol- class T. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell it, that T is a generic type in this case:

```
public <T> ExtA<T> filt(Func<T, Boolean> a)
```

You declared your interface with the symbol `T`, but that symbol is only valid in the interface declaration itself. The `T` you are using in your method is a different `T`. You have to declare it again, since the method is not implemented inside the interface declaration.

Comment: I don't know how your ExtA is declared. You should maybe edit the question, or create a new one...

Comment: Well, you have to declare it as ExtA<T>. The <T> tells the compiler, that it takes one type argument.

Comment: I guess you should also add the same type argument to ArrayList. But I don't really know.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the parameter on the method:

```
public <T> ExtA<T> filt(Func<T, Boolean> a) {
// method code
}
```