# Java generics incompatible type

Tags: java, generics, types

I have this method (using generics) :

```
public class ExtA<T>Ex<T> extends ArrayList
{    
    public<T> ExtA<T>Ex<T> filt(Function<T, Boolean> a...)
    {
  //code
    }
}
```

giving me an "incompatible types error".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics and generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908742/java-generics-and-generic-types)

Comment: Why did you change the question after accepting the answer?

Comment: Because I had another problem, still left the question relavant to the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the leading `<T>` from your `filt` method declaration. It's shadowing the generic `T` type applied to the class.

Comment: @user3126119 That should be fine, since it appears that you're adding behavior (the filtering) without changing the data structure of the class.

Comment: Always use the genericized type if available. In this case, the raw type should give you compiler warnings; pay attention to them.

Comment: @user3126119 Don't. Use `ExtA<T> eal3 = al.filt();`.

Comment: then how should I call it?

Comment: @user3126119 Like I just posted in that comment.

Comment: I tried but I need to call it from the main methods and it is telling me "cannot find symbol- class T"

Comment: @user3126119 You have to use the same class parameter you used for `al`.